# How to access a multiple dictionary in python?

Tags: python

I have a following dictionary:

```py
pokus = {1 : {"ahoj" : [{"visit" : [0, 0, 0]}]}}
```

Lets suppose I would like to print a value using `print(pokus[1]["ahoj"][0]["visit"][0])`. But I nedd `[1]["ahoj"][0]["visit"][0]` to be in an extra variable. I try this:

```py
pokus = {1 : {"ahoj" : [{"visit" : [0, 0, 0]}]}}

insert = [1]["ahoj"][0]["visit"][0]

print(pokus[insert])
```

But I get an error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` . Is there a way how to do that in Python? Thanks

Comment: You're trying to get `"ahoj"` from a new list `[1]` you just created, look at that line again. Like the error says, that list (`[1]`) doesn't have a string for an index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this with an extra variable alone, you need to use a function, e.g.:

```
def deep_at(obj, indices):
    for index in indices:
        obj = obj[index]
    return obj
```

With variables from your question:

```
pokus = {1 : {"ahoj" : [{"visit" : [0, 0, 0]}]}}
insert = [1, "ahoj", 0, "visit", 0]

deep_at(pokus, insert) == pokus[1]["ahoj"][0]["visit"][0]
# True
```

Comment: Nice! I'd probably define `indices` as `*indices` so you can do: `deep_at(pokus, 1, "ahoj", 0, "visit", 0)`

Comment: Worth mentioning the star magic, but the question indicates that s/he wants to have a variable to store the *"address"*, and that would require extra starring for use. I think it is cleaner this way.

Comment: Totally reasonable. Just highlighting it for others as an alternative :)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work with an extra variable.
With `insert = [1]` you're creating a new list `[1]` and since list indices can't be strings, this throws you the error.

To fix that use a function as @norok2 provided or the even simplier way just remove the extra variable:

```
pokus = {1: {"ahoj" : [{"visit": [0, 0, 0]}]}}

var = pokus[1]["ahoj"][0]["visit"][0]
print(var)
```

Output

```
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of lambda function may be a good alternative.

```
pokus = {1 : {"ahoj" : [{"visit" : [0, 0, 0]}]}}
desired_value = lambda pokus_dict: pokus_dict[1]["ahoj"][0]["visit"][0]

print(desired_value(pokus))
# output: 0
```